# Facebook appsecret_proof doesnt get append to the API - PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am trying to secure the Facebook API calls as per the document [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof)

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
    $appsecret_proof = hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $appSecret);
```

I tried to append the above after retreiving the `appsecret_proof`, it throws and error

**Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument thrown in base_facebook.php on line 1249**

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends?access_token=$access_token&appsecret_proof=$appsecret_proof');
```

Comment: What is the path that you are sending to Facebook?

Comment: I’d suggest you update your PHP SDK to the current version – that handles this on its own already.